# Odoo Table Partition

Tags: postgresql, triggers, odoo, table-partitioning

I'm working on Odoo and our database is grow and grow every days. I would like to do table partition for that and I have no experience on table partition process. First, I tried on new database. It was OK and then I worked on some functions and triggers for Odoo table partition. I got error.

Following is the insert functions and triggers for account_move and account_move_line tables.

```
------------- Create Partiton tables for 2020 ------------------
CREATE TABLE account_move_2020(
    CHECK ( create_date >= DATE '2020-01-01' AND create_date < DATE '2020-12-31' )
) INHERITS (account_move);
CREATE INDEX account_move_2020_create_date ON account_move_2020 (create_date);


CREATE TABLE account_move_line_2020(
    CHECK ( create_date >= DATE '2020-01-01' AND create_date < DATE '2020-12-31' )
) INHERITS (account_move_line);
CREATE INDEX account_move_line_2020_create_date ON account_move_line_2020 (create_date);

--------- Insert Function for Account Move -----------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_move_insert_function()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO account_move_2020 (id, is_bank_reconcilation, date, name, ref, journal_id, company_id, state, period_id, narration, received_by, rev_rate, is_wallet_tran, partner_id, to_check, create_uid, write_uid, create_date, write_date)  VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19)') using NEW.id, NEW.is_bank_reconcilation, NEW.date, NEW.name, NEW.ref, NEW.journal_id, NEW.company_id, NEW.state, NEW.period_id, NEW.narration, NEW.received_by, NEW.rev_rate, NEW.is_wallet_tran, NEW.partner_id, NEW.to_check, NEW.create_uid, NEW.write_uid, NEW.create_date, NEW.write_date;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

------- Trigger for Account Move Insert ------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER insert_account_move
    BEFORE INSERT ON account_move
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE account_move_insert_function();

--------- Insert Function for Account Move Line-----------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_move_line_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
BEGIN
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO account_move_line_2020 (id, create_date, statement_id, journal_id, currency_id,date_maturity, partner_id, reconcile_partial_id, blocked, analytic_account_id, create_uid, credit, centralisation, company_id, reconcile_ref, tax_code_id, state, debit, ref, account_id, period_id, write_date, date_created, date, write_uid, move_id, reconcile_id, tax_amount, product_id, account_tax_id, product_uom_id, amount_currency, quantity, bank_reconciled, to_reconcile, bank_stmt_reconcile_id, invoice_id, cpe_id, service_id, line_employee_id, payment_invoice_id, project, name, asset_id) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12,  $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24, $25, $26, $27, $28, $29, $30, $31, $32, $33, $34, $35, $36, $37, $38, $39, $40, $41, $42, $43, $44)') using NEW.id, NEW.create_date, NEW.statement_id, NEW.journal_id, NEW.currency_id, NEW.date_maturity, NEW.partner_id, NEW.reconcile_partial_id, NEW.blocked, NEW.analytic_account_id, NEW.create_uid, NEW.credit, NEW.centralisation, NEW.company_id, NEW.reconcile_ref, NEW.tax_code_id, NEW.state, NEW.debit, NEW.ref, NEW.account_id, NEW.period_id, NEW.write_date, NEW.date_created, NEW.date, NEW.write_uid, NEW.move_id, NEW.reconcile_id, NEW.tax_amount, NEW.product_id, NEW.account_tax_id, NEW.product_uom_id, NEW.amount_currency, NEW.quantity, NEW.bank_reconciled, NEW.to_reconcile, NEW.bank_stmt_reconcile_id, NEW.invoice_id, NEW.cpe_id, NEW.service_id, NEW.line_employee_id, NEW.payment_invoice_id, NEW.project, NEW.name, NEW.asset_id;
RETURN NEW;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

------- Trigger for Account Move Line Insert ------------------
CREATE TRIGGER account_move_line_insert_trigger
    BEFORE INSERT ON account_move_line
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE account_move_line_insert();
```

After running these queries, I created new Invoice from UI. When I validated the invoice I got error like this.

[image: Missing Error]

That error happened because of inserting data is not only on **partition table** but also on **master table** when I used **RETURN NEW** in insert functions. So I added new functions and trigger to delete master data like that.

```
-- Trigger function to delete from the master table after the insert
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_move_delete_master() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ONLY account_move where id = new.id;
    RETURN NULL;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Create the after insert trigger
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_account_move_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON account_move
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE account_move_delete_master();

-- Trigger function to delete from the master table after the insert
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION account_move_line_delete_master() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ONLY account_move_line where id = new.id;
    RETURN NULL;
end;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Create the after insert trigger
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_account_move_line_trigger
    AFTER INSERT ON account_move_line
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE account_move_line_delete_master();
```

After I run these queries and validated again from UI. But I got another error like this.

[image: key (move_id) = (###) is not present in table account_move]

What I found is the records is with the **same id** data in both master and partition table.

e.g. When I added new record, it inserted with index **id:11** in partition table. Now what happened in master table is including with 2 records with **id:11**.

When I tried to delete master data with id, it may also be deleted from partition data.

So, if you have any ideas for that, please share with me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use inheritance for partitioning, use [declarative partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE) - but neither support foreign keys _referencing_ the partitioned table.

Comment: What is your intended use case for partitioning? To be able to quickly remove old data? Or do you expect it to be a performance improvement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I would like to use for performance improvement. Now table size is so big and the system performance is slowing down.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about 100 million or more? Partitioning will **only** be a performance improvement if all (or at least all relevant) queries contain the partition key to allow for partition pruning. Especially if you expect this to improve performance you should use declarative partitioning and upgrade to Postgres 12 if you are not already using that.

Comment: now table is over 20 million but we have been growing every days. Now I am using postgresql 11.5

Comment: You should definitely use declarative partitioning then. But again: this will only be a performance improvement if every query contains the partition key, so that the optimizer can effectively apply partition pruning (and you still can't use foreign keys _referencing_ that table)

Comment: Thanks for your advise @a_horse_with_no_name. If you do not mind, I would like to know how to define the existing non partitioned table to partition table. I have no ideas for that and thanks again for your advise.